# Application Icons on Ubuntu Lockscreen

Tags: 20.04, lock-screen

I noticed that I had Remmina Icon on Ubuntu lockscreen, I don't know what this mean. Could you please explain ? Thank you.

[image: Remmina Icon]

Comment: Is there a Remote Desktop process active?

Comment: maybe it is in your startup apps

Answer (score 5):

It's showing a list of applications that have unread notifications since you locked your desktop.

In this case, Remmina had a notification for you, like that a remote session had disconnected.

> The lock screen means that you can see what is happening while your computer is locked, **and it allows you to get a summary of what has been happening while you have been away**.
>
> — https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-lockscreen.html.en